# React double execution

Tags: react-native

I'm working on a infinite scroll on scrollview, to do this I use Refrescontrol and that function:

```
    handleOnScroll(e){
        let yOffset = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
        if (this.state.hWall && this.state.hWall - this.state.hScreen - yOffset <= 0 && !this.state.isRefreshing){
            this.setState({ isRefreshing : true }, () => this.getPosts('more') );
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is that Alway I have two `this.getPosts('more')` calls, how to prevents double call before the getPosts action are completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that setState is asyncronous. Try using `this.isRefresing` to control whether there is a refresing ongoing or not.

```
handleOnScroll(e){
  let yOffset = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
  if (this.state.hWall && this.state.hWall - this.state.hScreen - yOffset <= 0 && !this.isRefreshing){
    this.isRefresing = true; //this is syncronous
    //setState is still required if you want to update your UI
    this.setState({ isRefreshing : true }, () => this.getPosts('more') );
  }
}
```

Furthermore, if you trade your scroll view for a flatList, you can use the `onEndReached` callback to fetch more data when the list is about to end.